# Function gets old variables (HtmlAgilityPack)

Tags: c#, .net, html, html-agility-pack

Well when I try to use foreach with few functions for getting text from HTML. Text is always the same for every iteration, BUT when i add breakpoint and check text which should be in foreach variable, it has changed. Here is code:

```
foreach (HtmlNode nodes in listingNode.ChildNodes)
                {
                    i++;
                    int row = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value = i; // ktory z kolei?
                    HtmlAttributeCollection imageNode = nodes.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='bmlistt']").Attributes; // image
                    string node = imageNode[1].Value; // link for that image
                    // add adding image to row
                    dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value = null; // image
                    //HtmlNode artistspan = artistNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='artist']");
                    dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[2].Value = nodes.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='maintext']").SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='artist']").InnerHtml; //returns always same text
                    dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[3].Value = null; // title
                    dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[4].Value = null; // difficulties
                    //dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[5].Value = null; // Checkbox
                    if (i == 10)
                    {
                        i++; // breakpoint
                    }
}
```

locals from breakpoint (after 10 iterations)

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/21125662/compilation/_01055.jpg

Orange lines shows what's wrong. (look at code, and then at screenshot) (node should be always the same as nodes )

Comment: maybe you need to itarate thru cells in your griid instread of using thr same ones

Comment: int row = dataGridView1.Rows.Add(); changes row, cells must be always same. And it doesn't really matter in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath can be bit tricky at first, when you want to select from a child node you have to add one '.' (dot) or your XPath will always select from the top node.

So...

```
nodes.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='bmlistt']").Attributes
```

becomes...

```
nodes.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='bmlistt']").Attributes
```